# Why does SwiftUI code run/reloae on iPhone and not on iPad?

Tags: swiftui

I have been looking at this code and other similar code for the last week and have a question.

The app (code link below) is a simple 5 question app in SwiftUI. Using an iPhone 11 simulator, the quiz runs perfectly and when you hit the back nav link and press the Start Quiz button, the quiz runs again. On an iPad however the Start Quiz button does not work to relaunch the Quiz.

I figured since both are running the same IOS, they should both function the same but they do not. Tried it on my physical iPad and the same thing. Runs through the quiz once, and will not run a second time. Anybody have any idea why? Thanks for your help!

https://github.com/albypanz94/Quiz-Game-in-SwiftUI.git

Comment: I suggest you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), instead of giving us your entire code to debug.

Comment: Sure. I am not sure where the problem lies however as I see no code specific to the iPad or iPhone. Thus, I am at a loss as to where the problem lies. I had no idea that code would function differently depending on device. I mean that it does not seem to be a layout issue.

Comment: SwiftUI does a bunch of things to adapt to different platforms. `NavigationView`/`NavigationLink`, for example, does a full screen transition in a narrow screen line the iphone, but shows master-detail side-by-side on a wide screen like the iPad

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the SwiftUI Navigation model is, by default, based on a UISplitview, and that on the iPad, the "Start Quiz" navigation link transfers navigation to its second controller. On an iphone, the second controller is collapsed away.

What this means for the game is that for the iPad (and large iPhones in landscape mode), the game cannot re-start.

You would also find anomalies if you ran the game on a large format iPhone, and then rotated it mid way through the game.

You can change the navigation view style to not use the split view model by using:

```
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

after the NavigationView closing brace.

Comment: Thank You. That makes perfect sense and is something that as a swiftUI newbie, had not know.

Comment: You are awesome and your wisdom is much appreciated!   Jerry